# Unable to determine the serialization information for

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, asp.net-core

While trying to Upsert a list @ MongoDB i get the following error:

```
"Unable to determine the serialization information for o => o."
```

Order.cs  **(removed properties for testing*):

```
public class Order
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)] 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }
```

Upsert:

```
public async Task SyncAsync(List<Order> orders) 
{

    var bulkUpdateModel = new List<WriteModel<Order>>();

    foreach (var order in orders)
    {
        var filter = Builders<Order>.Filter.Eq(o => o.Id, order.Id);

        var updateDefinition = Builders<Order>.Update.Set(o => o, order);
        var upsertOne = new UpdateOneModel<Order>(filter, updateDefinition) { IsUpsert = true };
        bulkUpdateModel.Add(upsertOne);
    }

    await _orders.BulkWriteAsync(bulkUpdateModel);
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to upsert an order?

Comment: Yes I have a list with orders which may or may not already exist... Also they might have updated properties. I want to upsert them all

Comment: you can pass a raw MQL in string form instead of expression form here: `o => o`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Yes, by posting an answer. Read: don't edit your question, post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the `ReplaceOneModel` instead:

```
var upsertOne = new ReplaceOneModel<Order>(filter, order)
{
    IsUpsert = true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

I found out that you can't update a whole document, only certain properties you set in the updateDefinition...

**Not working:**

```
var updateDefinition = Builders<Order>.Update.Set(o => o, order);
```

**Working:**

```
var updateDefinition = Builders<Order>.Update.Set(o => o.Whatever, order.Whatever);
```

I don't want to use reflection, so switched to Replace where it's possible to update the whole document.

### Example

```
public async Task SyncAsync(List<Order> orders) 
{
    var bulkUpdateModel = new List<WriteModel<Order>>();

    foreach (var order in orders)
    {
        var filter = Builders<Order>.Filter.Eq(o => o, order);
        var writeModel = new ReplaceOneModel<Order>(filter, order) { IsUpsert = true };
        bulkUpdateModel.Add(writeModel);
    }

    await _orders.BulkWriteAsync(bulkUpdateModel);
}
```

Comment: Which is my answer? lol

Comment: NOTE: `"Unable to determine the serialization information for o => o."` this error is not about that this way is not supported at all, it says that it's not supported by serialization, in other words, only particular `o => o` expression is not supported , a raw MQL request may or may not work here

Comment: May or may not lol, you just can't update whole doc like this.

Comment: I just explained the error you had, I used `may or may not` because I didn't check whether the solution of your expression-related issue work or no